# MongoDB: Ensure data is delivered and delivered only once

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-cluster

I have a theoretical problem with MongoDB:
I have an API that reads data from a MongoDB database. We have to make sure that each item in the collection is delivered eventually, but only once after it was inserted or changed. So the client needs the most recent version of the items, but only once, we must never send an item again if there was no change to it.

We first thought to achieve this by using a date: The client sends the date of the last query and we will only deliver the items that were created or changed after that date. The problem that I see is that we might miss items if part of the cluster is not available for some time and did not get synchronized with the rest. These items will never be delivered (as they were created after the last sync, did not sync with the rest and the client now has a newer "last fetched" time).

As this will not work, I thought about solving this with some kind of ACK-Flag, which is false on creation and true after it was sent to the client. After a change it would be set to false again. Here I see the problem that if someone changes the item while it is currently being sent to the client this change might be missing afterwards (the change says ACK=false, but the delivery says ACK=true afterwards).

This again does not seem to work as intended, so now I am thinking about some kind of optimistic locking where I store a version in the DB and update the ACK=true only if the version did not change from reading to writing.

This should work, but does not seem optimal at all (what if the call crashes while writing the ACK?). As this seems to be a common problem: What would be the best solution to this? Or is MongoDB just not the right tool for the job? Is it even possible to solve this if you expect that you have to scale vertically at some point?

Comment: *the client needs the most recent version of the items, but only once, we must never send an item again if there was no change to it.* sounds like you need to keep state either on client or server.